# Anaconda will not launch due to UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

My Anaconda won't launch on Win 10 after running Python code and will populate the UnicodeDecodeError shown below. If I re-install Anaconda, it will launch but the same decode error would show up again.

I have tried different methods discussed in other Stackoverflow questions like update conda or install clean-conda. I have also tried to remove content from the files where the error showed up, but none of them worked.

Would really appreciate it if anyone can provide insights.

```
(base) C:\Users\zchen2>anaconda-navigator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zchen2\Documents\Anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\zchen2\Documents\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 103, in main
    from anaconda_navigator.app.start import start_app
  File "C:\Users\zchen2\Documents\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 34, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.widgets.main_window import MainWindow
  File "C:\Users\zchen2\Documents\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\main_window.py", line 33, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.api.anaconda_api import AnacondaAPI
  File "C:\Users\zchen2\Documents\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\anaconda_api.py", line 28, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.api.client_api import ClientAPI
  File "C:\Users\zchen2\Documents\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\client_api.py", line 20, in <module>
    import binstar_client
  File "C:\Users\zchen2\Documents\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binstar_client\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .errors import *
  File "C:\Users\zchen2\Documents\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binstar_client\errors.py", line 1, in <module>
    from clyent.errors import ClyentError
  File "C:\Users\zchen2\Documents\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\clyent\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import iter_entry_points
  File "C:\Users\zchen2\Documents\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3239, in <module>
    def _initialize_master_working_set():
  File "C:\Users\zchen2\Documents\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3222, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zchen2\Documents\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3264, in _initialize_master_working_set
    tuple(
  File "C:\Users\zchen2\Documents\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3265, in <genexpr>
    dist.activate(replace=False)
  File "C:\Users\zchen2\Documents\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2778, in activate
    for pkg in self._get_metadata('namespace_packages.txt'):
  File "C:\Users\zchen2\Documents\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2762, in _get_metadata
    for line in self.get_metadata_lines(name):
  File "C:\Users\zchen2\Documents\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1415, in get_metadata_lines
    return yield_lines(self.get_metadata(name))
  File "C:\Users\zchen2\Documents\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1407, in get_metadata
    return value.decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 3: invalid continuation byte in namespace_packages.txt file at path: c:\users\zchen2\documents\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zope.interface-5.1.2.dist-info\namespace_packages.txt
```

If I open namespace_packages.txt in Notepad++ and set to UTF-8 encoding, the file will show ô„À/§"B°§V27. Deleting this line will allow Anaconda to launch with errors, so it would open the program selection window, but none of the program will run properly (like Jupyter Notebook).

Comment: Welcome JoStar! Does `namespace_packages.txt`contain any special characters?

Comment: Hi @jgmh When I open the namespace file using Notepad++ and set to UTF-8 encoding, it contains ô„À/§"B°§V27. If I delete this line and other similar files with error messages, anaconda will launch again but none of the program like Jupyter Notebbook would work properly.

Comment: I think you are trying to open a file that is not `utf-8`.  If you know the encoding used for that file, append it to the beginning of the file as explained in [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)